# Inspecting JSON strings produced with JsonCpp

Tags: jquery, c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) to encode/decode a deeply nested structure. So far, I have been able to convert my C++ object to JSON, but I am having problems going the other way back - I need to be able to inspect the Json::Value taht I have created.

The debuggers I have at hand (gdb, Netbeans IDE) are no use (or at least, I don't know how to use them) for inspecting the Json::Value.

Is there a tool I can use to inspect values like:

```
json["foo-elem"][idx1][idx2]
```

idx1 and idx2 are obviously (positive) integral values used to index into the nested structure.

I want to be able to parse the JSON string and then enter an expression to 'retrieve' elements of the JSON document, so that I can check that my nesting is as it should be.

Thinking laterally, IIRC, jQuery can be used (in FF) to select elements of a JSON object. Can anyone suggest a tool - or maybe simply how to use jQuery to inspect elements of the JSON string returned from JsonCpp?

Comment: JsonCpp really needs a gdb plugin, since their data structures are so hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Recent GDB can be [scripted with Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html). Then you might make your Python scripts to help you inspect such values.

Unfortunately, I cannot help you more, I am not familiar with that Python scripting ability.

Comment: I already have the gdb STL printing enhancements installed - however, gdb sill can't grok the Json::Value type

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli, If this is still a problem, file an [issue](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues). Seems interesting.